# iPad Camera OverlayView Orientation issue

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

My application is always run in Landscape mode only. I have add four custom buttons on overlay view dynamically. I want to change the position of buttons when orientation change in landscape and portrait mode.How to position my Camera Overlay View buttons in a different location when my device orientation will changing?

Please help me to fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: If your app is landscape only, how is orientation change part of the issue? You get notifications for orientation change through `UIViewController` methods: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` etc. Make any changes you want to the frame of buttons in these methods.

Comment: Yes, for this only i have used [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]. But i am not getting the correct button frame during device orientation.

Comment: So - you want to support both orientations? And if you are getting these orientation change notifications, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: yes, the problem is i am not getting correct button position.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  It's not that we're not receiving the notifications.  The problem is that the camera overlay view doesn't resize itself to fit the new orientation.  For example, the view will rotate when going from landscape to portrait but the view still has a landscape aspect ratio, i.e., the view is wider than it is high.